# Can't delete .xlsx file - Next Step?

Tags: vb.net, ioexception

I'm getting an IOException (file in use by another process) error when trying to delete an .xlsx file.  I moved the delete code to the front of Form_Load() just to make absolutely certain that nothing else I was doing was trying to open or read it.

Process Explorer can't find any references to the file to see what else might be trying to use it.

The file properties indicate that the user and system have full control.

I don't know what to look at next.

```
Private Sub PreEdit2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("\\HOSTNAME\Folder\Import Data\Other Import Files\" & "9710.xlsx")
```

I tried a local reference to the file just for good measure.

`My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Folder\Import Data\Other Import Files\" & "9710.xlsx")`

Really stumped here.  Any suggestions sincerely appreciated.

EDIT:

Modified my program to delete all kinds of other files in the same directory.  They delete with no problem.

Created an empty test program with one line that tries to delete the file
and it gets the same IOException.

So, my program isn't doing it.  The error says something else is using the file, no monitoring program I have used shows the any process involved with the file, and File Explorer can delete it?  Strange things are afoot at the Circle K.

EDIT 2:

I have moved the file and tried deleting it in lots of different directories.  I can delete it everywhere else I try it.  The only place I don't seem to be able to delete it (with my new single purpose test program) is in the directory it was originally copied to.  It should be remembered that all of the other files in that directory I can use the program to delete with no problem.

Comment: Maybe another application/service is currently using that file and not your application? For example: `Microsoft Excel` ?

Comment: Can you delete it manually via File Explorer? You might give [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/) a try.

Comment: @JQSOFT If only it were that easy.  I have checked Task Manager and checked the list of services running, in addition to MS Process Explorer which is supposed to show me what handles are referencing the files in question.

Comment: @InteXX I can delete it in File Explorer.  Lock Hunter says "No Processes locking this file or folder have been found".  My code still gets IOException "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  The only thing in my code that comes before the delete line are class variable declarations… unless something in VB executes before <ProgramName>_Load.

Comment: _unless something in VB executes before <ProgramName>_Load_ Yes there is. Check if you are accessing the file elsewhere in your code. In the constructor for example. If not, then try 1) Move the delete code in a button's click event for example to test it. 2) Run your app as administrator. 3) Restart your PC and try the original code. Maybe the file is being suspected by the anti virus/Windows security ...etc.

Comment: @JQSOFT I was pretty careful about where the file was being accessed.  But just for the heck of it I created a brand new program to try the delete of that particular file.  That program can't delete the file either.

Comment: @swinn How about other .xlsx files in the same directory? Or files like "9710.txt"? Can your program rename the problem file - and then delete it?

Comment: @swinn There is malware known as [Virus:Win32/Wide.9710.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Virus%3AWin32%2FWide.9710.dll&ThreatID=-2147421990) so it could be that Windows Defender has issues with the filename.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Good suggestions.  Other .xlsx files in the same directory delete fine.  9710.txt deletes fine too, although the original 9710.xlsx came to me as an email attachment and the 9710.txt file I just created (if that makes any difference).  Rename fails for the same reason -- used by another process.  I need to check into Windows Defender, but it would be strange to only have a problem with the file in this particular directory.  Windows Defender is turned off.  The anti-virus on the machine in question doesn't seem to have quarantined the file in any way.

Comment: `the original 9710.xlsx came to me as an email attachment` This might be a clue. In the file's Property Sheet dialog (Alt+Enter), is there an 'Unblock file' checkbox?

Comment: @InteXX The machine is running Windows 7.  If unblock is an option in that particular OS, it is not appearing in the file's properties dialog.  All of the other files in that directory came from email as well.

Comment: If the checkbox isn't there, the file's already unblocked. I'm out of suggestions, I'm afraid.

Comment: @InteXX In Windows 7, instead of a checkbox, it was a button with the text "Unblock". But I think the OP would have noticed it once you alerted them to it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton ~ If memory serves—and it doesn't—it was a button with the text "Unblock."